# How to pass argument to callback arrow function (JavaScript array.every)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a callback function which can be re-usable based on the argument that is passed while calling the function, It will be helpful to decide the behavior of callback function

Callback function:

```
  sampleArray = [5, 3, 4, 6, 7];

  getProcessedData = (value, args) => {
    console.log('manoj', args);
    if(args === 'value a') {
      ...
    } else if (args === 'value b') {
      ...
    }
    return;
  };
```

I using array.every() function on the above array

```
sampleArray.every(getProcessedData, 'value A');
sampleArray.every(getProcessedData, 'value B');
```

But I'm not able to receive this 'value A' in getProcessedData() function, I have tried with few other way, but it didn`t work. Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: `args` is an array, how can it be equal to a string?

Comment: My bad I was trying something, changed it

Comment: This also looks like TypeScript, not EcmaScript 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an anonymous function that passes the second argument.

```
sampleArray.every(el => getProcessedData(el, 'value A'));
```